# Multiple webview in an app or one

Tags: ios, html, animation

I'm creating an ios/android app that is implemented with partially native code and html5/css and built-in mobile webkit, I need to make it support both ios and Android, hence the html5/css selection. In my app I created a tabbar with 4 tab buttons, each tabview contains a webview, the tabs and tabbars are implemented natively, meaning the code for this is either objective-c or Java. What happens in those webviews are html5/css/js... I wonder if this is the appropriate way to implement it, or should I wrap the whole thing up in one single webview, and implement everything using html5, including the tabbar. Or let me ask this way, what did facebook do with its tabbars in its app? I'm concerning about user experience and seamless transition/animation.

If I can mimic the native ios/Android tabbar using html5, how may I? Anyone could maybe provide a link to a tutorial? Thanks!

Comment: Its depend on application complexity and future changes. It's fine to have native implementation for tabs. But personally I suggest you to go for html5 for that tabs too. About Facebook I heard that it was built on Phonegap tool. So even Facebook is not using native approach for tabs (because of multi platform support).

Comment: Any suggestion on how to make tab transition seamlessly using html5 then? I don't want to use PhoneGap in the first place, been there before, bad user experience... Maybe some JavaScript library so I don't have to reload the tab bar everyone the webview loads a new page?

Comment: Sorry, But I have no idea about that. You could search more for that, You will get any related help.